# How to write a date/time value?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

The [date/time format tokens](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#date_and_time_format_patterns) look straightforward. However, how do I use them to write a date value into a cell using the [spreadsheets.values.append method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)?

(I am coding in Node.js.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The values APIs are only for writing values themselves, not formats.  If you want to write formats, you need to use the [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) method, with either an [UpdateCellsRequest](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest), [RepeatCellRequest](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#RepeatCellRequest), or [AppendCellsRequest](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AppendCellsRequest).